# Using multiple `--tests`

Tags: testing, gradle, kotlin

After [building the Kotlin compiler](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin) (at commit e80a01a):

```
./gradlew dist
```

testing did not passed succesfully:

```
./gradlew compiler:test
```

Since very few test cases failed, I wanted to execute them again, excluding the succesful ones. It was possible, as long as I manually launched gradle *once per failing test* using the `--tests` option. For instance, both commands generated a single failing test:

```
./gradlew compiler:test --tests org.jetbrains.kotlin.code.CodeConformanceTest

./gradlew compiler:test --tests org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ir.IrBlackBoxCodegenTestGenerated\$Functions\$BigArity
```

However, if I tried to using `--tests` several times, it would failed with an error, without running the tests:

```
./gradlew compiler:test \
    --tests org.jetbrains.kotlin.code.CodeConformanceTest \
    --tests org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ir.IrBlackBoxCodegenTestGenerated\$Functions\$BigArity
```

Up to my understanding, Gradle documentation seems to state using the `--tests` option several times makes sense (see “[Testing in Java & JVM projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html)”):

> It is also possible to supply multiple `--tests` options, all of whose
>   patterns will take effect.

I'm hoping it's not a Kotlin issue. To me, it looks as an issue with Gradle or an issue with my understanding of Gradle (more likely). Any opinion on the matter?

Comment: *it would failed with an error* : which is ?

Comment: `No tests found for given includes: [org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ir.IrBlackBoxCodegenTestGenerated$Functions$BigArity$*](filter.includeTestsMatching)`

Comment: It's not about using `--tests` several times, it's about `org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ir.IrBlackBoxCodegenTestGenerated\$Functions\$BigArity` which does not contain any test

Comment: Well, if it does not contain any test, why does it work when used alone?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer. I was able to work around the issue by replacing test class package names by wildcards. This generated the same test failures as when calling gradle twice:

```
./gradlew compiler:test \
    --tests \*.CodeConformanceTest \
    --tests \*.IrBlackBoxCodegenTestGenerated\$Functions\$BigArity
```

I still fail to understand what's going on.